# Adding an extra remote repository in EGit

Tags: git, egit

I have 3 different git repositories:

1. An open source project
2. My own fork of the project on GitHub, which was forked from 1.
3. My local repository, which was cloned from 2.

I work on 3., and can push/pull changes to/from 2.

However, there are now changes in 1. which I would also like to merge into my own fork. I think what I want to do is pull the changes from 1. into a remote tracking branch in 3., do the merge locally, then push out to 2...... is that sensible?

If so, how do I best achieve this in EGit? In particular I'm not sure how I should get Egit to pull in the changes from 1. when it is already configured to push/pull from 2.

Comment: From the few times I've used it I've found egit to be a rather horrible way to interact with Git for all but the most basic operations. I'd highly recommend learning and using command-line Git instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do this in egit, but if you want to try command line.  First add a remote for repo 1:

```
    git remote add <remote_name> <url_of_open_source_project>
```

You can now see your remote repos by typing:

```
    git remote -v
```

Create a new branch which will be used to merge in repo's 1 code:

```
    git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

Fetch repo 1 and then merge repo 1's branch into your local branch:

```
    git fetch <remote_name>
    git merge <remote_name>/<remote's branch_name>
```

After this, you can push onto your github fork (assuming the remote name is `origin`):

```
    git push -u origin <github_branch_name>
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work pretty well! will accept if nobody comes up with a way to do within EGit itself.

Comment: @Alex - It's a useful answer, but doesn't strictly answer the question (which was about Eclipse EGit). I left the question open in case someone has a better answer that addresses EGit, which I would be happy to accept.

Comment: @mikera Fair enough. I just saw this part: "will accept if nobody comes up with a way to do within EGit itself" that was posted so long ago that it seemed unlikely anything would change soon.