# Configuring Eclipse / EGit to track an upstream repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm using EGit (as provided within the new Eclipse 4.2 Juno release).

I have a repository on GitHub which I have forked from another upstream repository.

When I create a project in Eclipse from the repository on Github, it correctly sets `origin` to point to the GitHub repository. But it doesn't yet know anything about the upstream repository (from which I want to merge changes).

I can successfully merge from the upstream repository manually (using "Team / Remote / Fetch From... / Custom URI " and providing the upstream repository details) however it is a bit tedious doing this every time.

However is there any way to tell Eclipse to merge from the upstream repository automatically?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526630/adding-an-extra-remote-repository-in-egit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the *Remotes* node in the git repository view, use *create remote*, enter "upstream" as name, select *configure fetch*. In the following dialog you can specify the refspec exactly as you did when you fetched manually.

Afterwards you have 2 entries under *Remote* and can easily fetch from one by using the context menu on the wanted node.

Comment: This is just half of the answer. Is there actually a way to do a pull from upstream master to the cloned fork master in EGit? Something like `git pull upstream master`

Comment: Quote from the user guide: "Ad-hoc selection of the upstream branch to pull from is not yet supported by EGit." So you need to merge the remote tracking branch instead.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Egit supports yet entering remote repo addresses directly within the GUI.

That means you best workaround would be to add that remote (upstream) repo reference manually, with a "`git remote add upstream ....`" (as in [this example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#Adding_a_dedicated_remote))

Then, you should see that remote reference listed in the "Remotes" node of your "Git repository view":

[image: Remotes node]

From there, you should be able to select the right remote, and pull from or push to said remote repo.