# Gitlab : fetching works but not pushing

Tags: push, gitlab, egit

I forked a project and fetch from amain project, but when i try to push into a my forked project i get

"can't connect to any repository..."

-I use Egit in eclipse-

the location of the destination repository, is defenetly right, because in the next step I can chose the target ref Name and there I can chose my branch.

Did i miss any read and write permissions or whats wrong there?

Comment: Do you see a remote url as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11399931/6309?

Comment: yes i do but if i click on push i get "Starting read stage without written request data pending is not supported"

Comment: strange: do you have a master.lock (as in http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/8350/)?

Comment: mh no the master.lock there is no master lock

Comment: ok when i try it with the gitGui i get : insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which version of Git and Egit and Eclipse?

Comment: git version 1.8.4 , eclipse indigo and gitlab is stored in a .cloudapp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto the GIT Repositories View(Window -> Show View -> Others->(in the text filter) GIT Repositories ).

[image: GIT Repositories View]

Check the Remotes -> Origin

If this Push and Fetch are missing

Right click on the Remote -> Add origin and configure

Check for the .gitignore file in your working directory which might sometimes help my friend.